# How to set an an object with a dynamic key as React state in Typescript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, state

I am using React and Typescript and need to create an object with a dynamic key that has two pre-defined properties. The field is dynamic so I can't pre-define it in Typescript. The structure I have attempted to implement in the interface is:

```
[field: string]: {
   property1: string,
   property2: string
}
```

I then want to be able to dynamically set the key of this object. Such as,

```
let item: string = "randomTest"

 this.setState({
    [item].property1: "test value 1"
 })
```

And access it through:

```
this.state[item].property1
```

However, when I attempt to implement this structure in the Typescript interface, the state keys that are not in the dynamic object throw an error saying they are "not assignable to string index type '{property1: string}'. For example, testKey1 below would throw this error:

```
[field: string]: {
   property1: string,
   property2: string
};
testKey1: string;
```

This error seems to be saying that testKey1 is in the [field] object even though it isn't.

How can I effectively define an object with a dynamic key as React state in Typescript?

Comment: Both keys in the object are `property2`, is that a typo?

Comment: yes, it is. i just changed that

Comment: What do you mean by dynamic keys. Do you mean what an object which can accept  every string as key. Or an object which accepts any key from specific set of strings? Please explain a little more.

Comment: I think it would be more understandable if you gave an example of what you want to achieve with real examples

Comment: I added an example of what I'm attempting to accomplish. Basically, I want to be able to dynamically set the object's key.

Comment: Have you ever set a dynamic key in React?

Comment: I don't understand why that's confusing.

Comment: Maybe we aren't understanding your reasoning, copy the piece of code of what you are doing and we'll see more clearly what it is :)

Comment: it's in the question. please re-read.

Comment: I want to be able to dynamically set the key of this object. Such as,

let item: string = "randomTest"

 this.setState({
    [item].property1: "test value 1"
 })
And access it through:

this.state[item].property1

Comment: Something like this example to update the fields based on the value of the key you add to the method? https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ts-a72oui

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/206289/discussion-between-fg93-and-dog).

Comment: Is it possible this? https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ts-askytn?file=index.html

Answer (score 1):

Replace

```
[field: string]: {
   property1: string,
   property2: string
}
```

by

```
    interface Anything {
      [key: string]: any;
    }
```

And when you're calling then: do this

```
let item = { property1: "randomTest", property2: "randomTest1", property3: "randomTest3"}

 this.setState({
    [item].property1: "test value 1"
 })
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a semecon before testKey1: string;

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Record built-in type added in TypeScript 2.1. Record

```
interface MyObject {
  property1: string;
  property2: string;
}

type DynamicObject = Record<string, MyObject>;
```

Comment: I've tried defining an interface as a value to the dynamic key but that doesn't work.

Comment: For example, [field: string]: MyObject throws and error.